# Joint distribution of two related sample variances

Tags: distributions, variance, sample, joint-distribution, moments

Consider three time series x, v, w 
The distribution of the values that x,v,w take are zero-mean Gaussian, stationary and independent of time (no temporal colleration) and of each other. We know the population variance of v and w but not x.

If we now consider the sample variances of the time series x+v and of the time series x+w
These sample variances Sv and Sw are known to follow a Pearson Type III distribution formula (according to the Mathworld Sample Variance Distribution page)

I require to know the joint distribution of the sample variance pair [Sv, Sw]. I had thought about generating all the moments analytically but not sure if that will help (if i recall correctly this only defines the distribution exactly in special cases). Alternatively deriving some correlation coefficent and approximating with a bivariate Gaussian distribution. Unfortunately i really would prefer the exact solution.